# Color and underline in wysiwyg field

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm developing with backpack for laraver and I'm using wysiwyg field. I would like to use underline and change font color. I'm searched in ckeditor webpage and it seems it supports these functions. 
How can I enable them?

Best regards

Edit - I don't understand why I'm receiving negatives for this question. What I'm doing wrong?

Edit 2- 
Thank you Delighted,
Here is the code I'm using, but forecolor option seems not to be working. The button does not appear.

```
$this->crud->addField([  
            'name'  => 'desc1',
            'label' => 'Descipción 1',
            'type'  => 'tinymce',
            // optional overwrite of the configuration array
            'options' => [
                'selector' => 'textarea.tinymce',
                'skin' => 'dick-light',
                'plugins' => 'image,link,media,anchor',
                'toolbar' => 'undo redo formatselect fontsizeselect bullist numlist link image bold italic underline forecolor',
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Re: Edit - Generally speaking, most users here at SO expect to see some code showing what you have or what you've tried. Asking a question without providing the code you're asking about is often considered bad form. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got that. I had to add textcolor and colorpicker as plugins.
The resultant code is as follows.

```
$this->crud->addField([  
            'name'  => 'desc1',
            'label' => 'Descipción 1',
            'type'  => 'tinymce',
            // optional overwrite of the configuration array
            'options' => [
                'selector' => 'textarea.tinymce',
                //'statusbar' => false,
                'skin' => 'dick-light',
                'plugins' => 'image,link,media,anchor,textcolor,colorpicker',
                'toolbar' => [
                    'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | forecolor',
                    'alignleft aligncenter alignright'
                ]
            ],
        ]);
```

Thank you very much Delighted00

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `options` index in the field configuration [which is documented here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-fields#tinymce)

Essentially, you'll want to include the `options` index in your field configuration and add to it any of the options that you would normally pass to the javascript init method of TinyMce if you were using it manually.

The specific option you want is the `toolbar` option. [Here's a list of controls you can add to the toolbar](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols)

Here's a quick example:

```
$this->crud->addField([  
            'name'  => 'description',
            'label' => 'Description',
            'type'  => 'tinymce',
            // optional overwrite of the configuration array
            'options' => [
                'selector' => 'textarea.tinymce',
                'skin' => 'dick-light',
                'plugins' => 'image,link,media,anchor',
                'toolbar' => 'forecolor underline',
            ],
        ]);
```

For a closer look at exactly how these options are passed to tinymce, see [the tinymce field blade template](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/fields/tinymce.blade.php) lines 33 - 50